# Retrieve number after space from string

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I'm trying to parse an address so I can retrieve the address, address number and address letter.

```
string address = "Mushroom road 2b";
```

I'm trying to retrieve

```
var addressName = "Mushroom Road";
var addressNumber = "2";
var addressLetter = "b";
```

I've tried to use split and parse it with substring.

```
   string adress = "Mushroom road 2b";
   string temp = adress;

   var res = temp.Substring(temp.IndexOf(' '));
   //check if res first letter = number?
   //Not sure how to use regex really
   var addressNumber = Regex.Replace(temp, @"[^\d]", "");
```

res will be road 2b. But I want to retrieve first Mushroom road, then 2, then b.

Comment: Are your strings always in this format?

Comment: The string is not necessarily in this format. It could be `Mushroom 2b` or `Mushroom road 2 b` or even be missing the letter sometimes `Mushroom 2`

Comment: As @juFo mentions, this can be done with (relatively) simple regex. Have a look at regex groups. You can test it out with sites like this: https://regex101.com/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try *regular expressions*, e.g.:

```
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  var match = Regex.Match(
      source, 
    @"(?<street>[A-Z][A-Za-z'\s]*)(?<number>[0-9]+)\s*(?<letter>[a-zA-Z]*)"); 

  if (match.Success) {
    // "Mushroom Road"
    var addressStreet = match.Groups["street"].Value.Trim(); 
    // "2"
    var addressNumber = match.Groups["number"].Value;
    // "b"
    var addressLetter = match.Groups["letter"].Value; 
    ...
  }
```

Pattern `(?<street>[A-Z][A-Za-z'\s]*)(?<number>[0-9]+)\s*(?<letter>[a-zA-Z]*)` means

```
  (?<street>[A-Z][A-Za-z'\s]*) one capital letter A..Z followed by 
                               zero or more letters (a..z A..Z), 
                               apostrophes and whitespaces  
  (?<number>[0-9]+)            one or more digits
  \s*                          zero or more whitespaces  
  (?<letter>[a-zA-Z]*)         zero or more letters a..z A..Z
```

**Demo:**

```
string[] tests = new string[] {
  "Mushroom road 2b",
  "Mushroom road 2 b",
  "Mushroom 2"
};

var results = tests
  .Select(test => new {
    test,
    match = Regex.Match(
        test,
      @"(?<street>[A-Z][A-Za-z'\s]*)(?<number>[0-9]+)\s*(?<letter>[a-zA-Z]*)")
  })
  .Select(item => new {
    test = item.test,
    street = item.match.Groups["street"].Value.Trim(),
    number = item.match.Groups["number"].Value,
    letter = item.match.Groups["letter"].Value
  })
  .Select(item => 
     $"{item.test,-20} => \"{item.street}\"; \"{item.number}\"; \"{item.letter}\"");

string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, results);

Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
Mushroom road 2b     => "Mushroom road"; "2"; "b"
Mushroom road 2 b    => "Mushroom road"; "2"; "b"
Mushroom 2           => "Mushroom"; "2"; ""
```

Comment: Suppose this would work, but how would I get the address name? `Mushroom road`

Comment: This works for now! thanks! Might get to some edgecases but a good one for the first draft!

Answer (score -2):

The Split method might we useful.

```
var parts = address.Split(' ');
addressName = parts[0];
addressNumber = parts[1];
addressLetter = parts[2];
```

or use regular expressions with groups.

Misread.

You can now use e.g. parts[2] and use .Substring.

You can iterate all characters also and test them. Char class has some useful methods.

Comment: I didn't down vote, but this doesn't give `Mushroom road`, `2` and `b`.